# How to add cursors data into listView

Tags: android-listview, android-cursorloader

How to add cursor returned by **sql query** into **listview**.
**I created:**

- a `database` of **personal details**
- A form to feed data, which have submit,delete and show button. 
  Show button is intended to show all names inserted int database into a different activity, and on selecting i want to show full detail corresponding to that detail.

I have tried to add cursor returned by `readData` Named function  which returns cursor of query `"select * from <tablename>"` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe...

- Define your own ListView sub item XML, show your data.
- Or, simply dump your Bean data to a String, so that you can easy show it on ListView.

**Edit for reply your comment**

What you needs are

1. Java Bean
2. SQL script (I believe you already know)
3. Bundle & intent data (to send something to next Activity)

You can use a simple ListView to show only "name" on it.
When you click on this "name ListView", you can get index from ListView, so that you will know what item you really click.

So now, you have enough key to show "full detail" info in next Activity.

Comment: I want to show only "name" field  from cursor. So the main issue is of retrieving selected field value from each row of curso. Secondly i want  to show full detail on item selection.

Comment: Answer above, check it out.